# How to prune the aposDocVersion table

Tags: apostrophe-cms

As I understand it, the aposDocVersions table shows the last few (or even all?) previous versions of pieces, its history. We are using apostrophe-workflow, but I am not certain it's specifically related to this.

There are a ridiculous amount of entries in there, and in all honesty, we wish to simply remove them, as we don't use that part of the feature (only the submit vs commit logic).

Is there a way to only keep let's say only the last two commits, and delete everything else safely?

Answer (score 1):

There is an `enabled: false` option on the `apostrophe-versions` module. It will disable the feature completely. That said, it's a bit of a stub of a feature since you will still have buttons for the UI that simply no longer work . Generally speaking, disabling that is somewhat antithetical to the approach for data in A2.

Apostrophe 3 does not have this kind of version storage, so you're good if you update.

If you do want to try to reduce the number saved, you could try overwriting [the `self.pruneOldVersions` method in apostrophe-versions](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/479b56978a5c3b76589fd1538a3b3105c55e5260/lib/modules/apostrophe-versions/lib/api.js#L63-L104).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I'll investigate. Maybe manually pruning every so often could do the job.